# MacBook restarted now no HD to work from

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I was using my 2012 era MacBook Pro when it suddenly restarted, to a folder with a ? On it. When I try any of the internet recovery methods, it just says disk 0 and base recovery system. So I can’t reinstall any OS X. And if I try to reinstall it no disk pops up. So is my laptop toast?

Comment: Have you tried a usb stick with an installer? Have you tried using an external disk to boot and check the internal drive?

Comment: I haven’t tried a USB stick, mainly because I have no source for an installer. The other computer in the house is windows. I have a external drive I could try though